# Splitting CSV file in s3 while preserving header row

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking to split a large CSV file that lands in an S3 bucket using lambda into a different S3 bucket. The input would look something like this: `uniqueid.csv` and I would want the output of files to look like this: `uniqueid_01.csv, uniqueid_02.csv, etc.`

However, in the output CSV files I want to preserve the header row of the CSV in all the files.

My understanding is that I can use a bash script with something like this article: https://www.dtraskas.io/articles/s3splitter/, however, I am unsure how to preserve the header row.

Comment: A bash script is not going to be ideal if you want to run this on Lambda. Certainly you could probably make it work, but it's likely to be better to simply use a programming language such as Python and a suitable AWS SDK (e.g. boto3) to read/write the various S3 objects.

Comment: @jarmond this isn't true - you can actually choose "use default bootstrap on Amazon Linux" when creating a lambda function to use bash

Comment: I didn't say that you could not do this with bash scripting. Just proposing that writing this in Python with the csv and boto3 libraries would likely be a better solution.